# Converting to Linestring using Dataframe Column

Tags: python, shapely

I'm attempting to convert tuples from a dataframe into a linestring. This is part of my dataframe imported from a csv file.

```
   Unnamed: 0       name        route                                             decode
0          0        Funshine!  ofosF|mqaShJ@?rLh@d@veCIVd@LbEJfJ^f@lE?Rp@^L~g...  [(-105.279, 40.060), (-105.279, 40.058...
```

If I manually copy and paste the contents of the decode column into the LineString() condition aka

```
line = LineString([(-105.279, 40.060), (-105.279, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.03), (-105.28, 40.036), (-105.283, 40.036), (-105.285, 40.036), (-105.285, 40.036)]
```

It converts it. But if I try to do the same thing by specifying the column and row, it fails.

```
line = LineString(df.decode[0])
print(line)
```

This is the error I receive. It is posted below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 86, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/taylo/PycharmProjects/PermitProj/Polyline Decode.py", line 20, in <module>
    line = LineString(df.decode[1])
  File "C:\Users\taylo\Miniconda3\envs\ExcelPermitExe\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\Miniconda3\envs\ExcelPermitExe\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 97, in _set_coords
    ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 166, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
AssertionError
```

How do I write this so that I avoid this error and can convert the tuples to a column in my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```py
line = df.decode.apply(lambda row: LineString(eval(row)))
```

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: Is the column a string?

Comment: I believe so, the dtype is object and I also set df['decode'] = df['decode'].astype(str) to make sure.

Comment: Just updated to something that might work.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!!

Comment: Great - just be aware that eval is useful, but could be unsafe depending on what is thrown in the string. So, only use the script on trusted files.

Comment: Trusted files as in files I've created? What does eval do?

Comment: Trusted files as in the ones you create or from someone you trust. eval executes the string as if it were python code. It was the simples method I found do convert what you had to a Python object. Here is a useful link for caution: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html